# want to shortest method if string is not null then add otherwise not

Tags: android

I want to add street ,city,zipcode,country if these are not equals to null,
if street is null then donot add street, i have method , but i want to get shortest and best method for this...

```
map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, street+" "+city +" " +zipcode+ " "+country);
```

my method is this

```
if(street.trim().length()>0&&city.trim().length()>0&&zipcode.trim().length()>0&&country.trim().length()>0)
    {
     map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, street+" "+city +" " +zipcode+ " "+country);
     }
 else if(){

   }
 else if(){

     }
```

i want shortest method to check all strings are null then donot add that string into map...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all the Strings in an Array, in an Order:

```
String[] sa = new String{street, city, zipcode, country};

private String getAddress(String[] sa){

String s = "";
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

if(sa[i] != null){
s = s + " " + sa[i].trim();
}
}
return s;
}
```

Comment: don't forget to add spaces between elements. Also you will have to add the space only if the element is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method as below. `...` means variable parameters.

```
public boolean AnyNullOrEmpty(String ... strs)
{
    for(String s : strs) {
        if(s == null)
            return false;
        if(s.trim().length() == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Call it:

```
if(NoneNullOrEmpty(street, city, zipcode, country)) {
    // do watever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in utility class to test strings as null or empty: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Also, you can use StringBuilder to build your String from parts.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
String[] lines = {street, city, etc...}
for(String l : lines){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(l)){
        b.append(l).append(" ");
    }
}
String address = b.toString();
```

Comment: It would be if he had used StringBuilder or StringBuffer instead of String concatenation. (Mine would be greatly improved with a loop, however, I'll add that now)

Answer (score 1):

```
map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, validate(street, true), true)+validate(city, true)+ validate(zipcode, true)+validate(country, false));


private String validate(String value, final boolean append)
{
    value = ( value != null ) ? value.trim() : value;
    return (value != null && value.length() > 0) ? value + (( append ) ? " " : "") : "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map.put(checkString(street)+checkString(city)+checkString(zip)+checkString(country));

public String checkString(String str)
{
return str.trim().length()>0?str:"";
}
```